# Drupal 7 - why is my action not showing up in the triggers menu?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I've added a second element to the `userbeep_action_info()` hook which I plan to make into a new action, but when I check it in the Triggers page, it doesn't appear. The first item, `userbeep_beep_action` shows, but not the second. Why is this? Is it because it's configurable that it needs extra information to appear? My book asks me to check for its presence at this stage but it isn't appearing.

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Writes to the log every time a user logs in or edits a node.
 */

/**
 * Implementation of hook_action_info().
 */
function userbeep_action_info() {
    return array(
        'userbeep_beep_action' => array(
            'type' => 'system',
            'label' => t('Beep annoyingly'),
            'configurable' => FALSE,
            'triggers' => array('node_view', 'node_insert', 'node_update', 'node_delete')
        ),
        'userbeep_multiple_beep_action' => array(
            'type' => 'system',
            'label' => t('Beep multiple times'),
            'configurable' => TRUE,
            'triggers' => array('node_view', 'node_insert', 'node_update', 'node_delete')
        )
    );
}

/**
 * Simulate a beep. A Drupal action.
 */
function userbeep_beep_action() {
    watchdog('beep', 'Beep! at ' . '');
}
```

Comment: I know the book you're using. You'll want to bookmark this site for future reference - http://www.drupalbook.com/errata_overview

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer below if it's helped you. This is a good book apart from all the mistakes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Book's error corrections site - http://www.drupalbook.com/errata3

> Error:  The screenshot in Figure 3.4 is of the wrong overlay. (What is
>   shown in Figure 3.4 is not available until an instance of the advanced
>   action has been created as described on pp. 43-44 and in Figure 3.5.)
>
> Correction:  What should be shown in Figure 3.4 is the overlay
>   accessed by clicking the Configuration link in the top menu and then
>   clicking on the Actions link in the Configuration page, and finally
>   scrolling to the bottom of the overlay to the "Create an Advanced
>   Action" drop-down select box.

The figure you're basing your assumption that your code isn't working isn't the right one. Complete the rest of the chapter and you'll get it working. Use the resource above to hunt down more errors in the book.

**Hint:** There are quite a few...

Answer (score 0):

It is not showing up because advanced (configurable) actions need to be created and configured once defined in code at: `/admin/config/system/actions`, where as simple actions do not. It may also require the configuration form and actions to be defined first as well.